# Deciding between np hard and np complete in my own set of rules

Tags: python, c, np-complete, np-hard

I have the `Iris dataset` which looks something like:

```
1,3,1,1,0
1,1,1,1,0
1,3,1,1,0
1,2,1,1,0
1,3,1,1,0
1,2,1,1,0
2,2,2,2,1
2,2,2,2,1
2,2,2,2,1
2,1,2,2,1
1,1,2,2,1
2,1,2,2,1
2,2,3,4,2
2,1,3,4,2
3,1,3,4,2
2,1,3,4,2
2,1,3,4,2
3,1,3,4,2
```

I am just giving 18 rows but there are total 150 rows. The 1st 4 column gives the 4 attribute values and the fifth column gives the class.

So `3,1,3,4,2` means if the `att_1=3, att_2=1, att_3=3, att_4=4` the `class=2`

Now I have written 2 classifier algorithms, where I tried to extract rules from this dataset.

The 1st algorithm(Implemented using C and python) gives the output as:

```
*,*,1,*,0
*,*,2,2,1
*,*,*,3,1
*,*,*,4,2
*,*,3,*,2
```

By these above 5 rows I tried to keep all the characteristics of the main dataset which contains 150 rows. Here `*` stands for `don't care` and `*,*,2,2,1` this simply means if the value of attribute 3 and 4 =2 then we don't care about the value of attribute 1 and 2, the class will be = 1.

The 2nd algorithm(Implemented using C and python) gives the output as:

```
*,*,1,*,0
*,*,2,2,1
2,*,*,3,1
*,2,2,*,1
*,*,3,4,2
*,1,*,4,2
*,*,3,2,2
3,*,*,*,2
1,*,*,3,2
```

Now I took the union of these 2 rule sets. And got the outcome as:

```
*,*,2,2,1
*,*,1,*,0
*,2,2,*,1
*,*,3,2,2
*,*,3,4,2
3,*,*,*,2
*,*,*,3,1
1,*,*,3,2
*,*,*,4,2
*,*,3,*,2
*,1,*,4,2
2,*,*,3,1
```

Now the question that is arriving in my mind is, there are 12 rules in that union file. But may be there can be 3 or 4 most effective rules, using which we can get the clear view of the initial iris dataset with 150 rows. So my point is : To find the top 5 most effective rules from this above union rules. Basically I got those rules from the initial iris dataset and now I want to get the initial iris dataset back from the best possible generated rules. Is this problem a `np-hard` or a `np-complete` problem? And why so?

Comment: I just want to know is there any way that I can select a subset of those 12 rules which may give the proper idea of my initial dataset in polynomial time?

Comment: Can you tell me in a detailed manner please. May be it is not making much sense but I am having this question in mind for the last few hours so thought of asking.

Comment: The answer is that it is never possible to find a uniquely defined data set back from the rules. There are infinitely many data sets leading to the same rule. Just imagine a doubled data set that will lead to the same model, because there is no new information in it, compared to the smaller data set.

Comment: @Nechoj I got your point that `infinitely many data sets leading to the same rule` but is there any way that I may know the best possible from them which can give me the near optimum solution?

Comment: From a formalistic viewpoint this is not in the competition to be np-complete as those are decision problems (=they output one bit: yes/no). Overall the problem is not well-defined enough. "top 5 most effective rules" - how would you formalise that? Will it always be five? Even talking about complexity in a problem with constant dimensions falls apart, as long the input is always 5x150, almost any algorithm on it run in O(1), as there is no N to analyze.

Comment: ... define "best possible" and "optimum solution". You may have an intuitive understanding of what that is, but is it a well-defined concept?

Comment: @dratenik here I have taken a very small dataset just to make things a little easy to explain. This can be `5xn` where `n` is a huge number. `top 5 most effective rules ` this need not be 5, this can be say `x` where `x` is the smallest possible integer number.

Comment: define "most effective" then

Comment: @dratenik which has the best accuracy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239959/discussion-between-dratenik-and-dev).